# NUL characters after JAXB marshalling

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, jaxb

I've been using the JAXB libraries to read & write XML files for a while now, without any issues. However, I've recently had issues where NUL characters are written to the XML files during marshalling.

Strange thing is, this issue has only cropped up when testing on Turkish version of Windows. I can't reproduce them on English or Japanese (the only platforms I have access to atm) distributions. Any idea what could be causing this? Example code below.

Marshalling Class:

```
public class InputsMarshaller {

    public static Inputs unmarshal(String filePath) {
        Inputs inputs = null;
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Inputs.class); //1
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();    
            inputs = (Inputs) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(filePath));
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }    
        return inputs;
    }

    public static void marshal(Inputs inputs, String filePath) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Inputs.class); //1
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.marshal(inputs, new FileWriter(new File(filePath)));   
        } catch (IOException | JAXBException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }        
    }
}
```

Inputs Class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "inputs")
public class Inputs {

    private ArrayList<String> values;
private String name, unit;

    @XmlElement(name="values")
    public List<String> getValues() {
        if(values == null) {
            values = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return values;
    }

@XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

@XmlAttribute(name = "unit")
    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with any of your code.  What does the output look like?